# use var outside socket.io scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm making a chat in nodejs and i want to use the var user outside the socket.io scope but it keep giving me a undefined

here is my code that sets the user var

```
socket.on('bio', function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    users[data[i].name] = {
                            avatar: data[i].avatar,
                            steamid: data[i].steamid,
                            name: data[i].name,
                            userid: data[i].id,
                            admin: data[i].admin
                    }
            }
    });
```

and here i try to use it but it says its undefined

```
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var self = this;

        if (event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey === false) {
            socket.emit('input', {
                timeStamp: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
                name: chatName,
                userid: users[chatName].id,
                message: self.value
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

it probably something stupid but I'm still in the learning phase :D

Comment: Have you created var users={};  in global scope?

Comment: yes i have just above the socket.on but when i console log  it out in the key down function it gives this `{}`

Comment: And are you sure the socket call ran?

Comment: UPDATE - found the issue in the socket.emit i had to use `id: users[chatName].id` instead of `userid: users[chatName].id`

Comment: @HyperGainZ you can also just do `users[data[i].name] = data;`

Comment: @HyperGainZ Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @Garrett yes i did thx

Comment: @HyperGainz Would you mind marking one of the answers as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hoisting problem in javascript.

example:

```
var v = "hello";
(function(){
  console.log(v);
  var v = "world";
})();
```

will be like this

```
var v = "hello";
(function(){
  var v; //declaration hoisting
  console.log(v);
  v = "world";
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set users in the global scope. At the top of your code just write:

```
var users = {};
```

That should get it working.

Just as some extra explanation, right now you are creating your users variable inside of that 'bio function', so anything that is not inside of that function doesn't know about the existance of your users variable. Declaring it in the global scope of your class, aka not inside of a function, lets all of your functions see it. This also means that once it gets assigned a value inside one function, it retains its value when used in other functions.